# Odoo10 xpath inherit field on purchase order line

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm trying to code on module.

but i'm stuck. it doesn't work.

Python code

```
class PurchaseCurrency(models.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order.line"

    new_currency = fields.Float(string="Test")
```

my xml

```
<record id="new_currency_line" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_qty']" position="after">
                <field name="new_currency"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
</record>
```

and error warning

ValueError: Field `new_currency` does not exist

Error context:
View `purchase.order.form`
[view_id: 1074, xml_id: purchase.purchase_order_form, model: purchase.order, parent_id: n/a]

anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you import your python files and restarted Odoo?

Comment: i did it already

Comment: Can you please add all Errors of you server log here? Maybe there is another Error or the log that will show other things you might not have seen.

Comment: ValueError: Field `new_currency` does not exist

Error context:
View `purchase.order.form`
[view_id: 1074, xml_id: purchase.purchase_order_form, model: purchase.order, parent_id: n/a]

Comment: Can you please check if the field is in the database for table purchase_order_line? That really is very weird. I don't see a mistake in the provided code. It has to be in code you haven't provided yet.

Comment: Thank for helping. but now i solved by update core module.

Comment: That's not really satisfying not to know where the real issue was :-P

Answer (score -1):

Add your python model file to `__init__.py`
    from . import model

Make sure your python model directory is imported in modules root `__init__.py`
    from . import models

Restart your odoo instance and update the module from web backend or using `-u module_name` from command line.

You can simplify `xpath` expression by using `field` tag

```
<record id="new_currency_line" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form.new</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="product_qty" position="after">
        <field name="new_currency" />
    </field>
</record>
```